# Defining Variables that are accessible page wide

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Good morning guys,

I am working on vb.net. The aim is to make a CodeFile run some sql queries and then return the values to the webpage as an sqldatasource query parameter on page load.

I have the following vb code

```
Partial Class Consult
Inherits Page
Public totalCount As Integer = "0"

'*******Here i declare the variable***************    
Public Property PatNo() As String
    Get
        Return ViewState("PatNo")
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ViewState("PatNo") = value
    End Set
End Property

Public PatNam As String = "abc"
Public ConID As String = "abc"
Public TreatType As String = "abc"
Public HPC As Char = "abc"
Public LvTyp As RadioButtonList



Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.PatNo = Request.QueryString("pNo")
    Session("PatientNo") = PatNo
    Dim ConsultationID As String = Request.QueryString("consultID")
    ConID = ConsultationID
    Response.Write(PatNo)

    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DefaultConnection").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
'**********BELOW LINE CAUSES ERROR**************
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM hPatients WHERE pNO=@PatNo" 
        query += "SELECT * FROM hPatients WHERE pNO='001/000034824'"
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PatNo
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using ds As New DataSet()
                    sda.Fill(ds)
                    gvPatientInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    'Return ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2)
                    'Response.Write(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(2))
                    gvPatientInfo.DataBind()
                    gvClientInfo.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
                    gvClientInfo.DataBind()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

        'Dim di As DataInfo = Me.GetInfo()


        'Populating a DataTable from database.
        Dim dt As DataTable = Me.GetData()
        'Response.Write(ConID + " " + PatNo)
        'Building an HTML string.
        Dim html As New StringBuilder()

        'Table start.
        html.Append("<table border = '1' class = 'table'>")

        'Building the Header row.
        html.Append("<tr>")
        For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            html.Append("<th>")
            html.Append(column.ColumnName)
            html.Append("</th>")
        Next
        html.Append("</tr>")

        'Building the Data rows.
        For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            html.Append("<tr>")
            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                html.Append("<td>")
                html.Append(row(column.ColumnName))
                html.Append("</td>")
            Next
            html.Append("</tr>")
        Next

        'Table end.
        html.Append("</table>")

        'Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New Literal() With { _
           .Text = html.ToString() _
         })
    End If
End Sub
```

The error i get is

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@PatNo".
```

The error occurs in the first step of getting the variable to execute the query in the page_load function.

The second step would be to get the result of the query and use on the webpage.

Somebody, Anybody, Please HELP!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("PatNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PatNo
```

Change the name from "PatNo" to "@PatNo" and it should work.

Comment: Good observation Marc, but it still doesnt work. I still get the same error. Post corrected though.

Comment: Fair enough. I assume the line "query += "SELECT * FROM hPatients WHERE pNO='001/000034824'" is there intentionally? I'm getting a similar error when I include that line...

Comment: Thanks Marc you saved me. Now on to a new question